# When should I flag an answer as "not an answer"?

Tags: support, faq, flagging

I flagged an answer as "not an answer," but my flag was declined saying that the flag should not be used for a wrong answer.

In which cases should an answer be flagged as "not an answer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag "not an answer" should be used when:

- The answer was written by the OP who wrote an answer instead of editing the question to give more information
- The answer was written by the OP who wrote an answer to ask more information to a user who wrote an answer
- The answer was written by a user having the same problem as the OP, and wanting to know if the OP found a solution
- The answer was written by a user to get more information about the question
- The answer was written by a user to ask a different/related question

If somebody gives the wrong answer, there is nothing moderators can do. Wrong answers can be down-voted, but moderators should not be asked to judge the correctness of answers.

#### References

- [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/160923)